# What's the difference between the magical abilities of men and women?

Tags: earthsea

In the first book of Earthsea there is a passage about 'Woman's Magic':

> There is a saying on Gont, **Weak** as woman's magic, and there is
>   another saying, **Wicked** as woman's magic. Now the witch of Ten
>   Alders was no black sorceress, nor did she ever meddle with the high
>   arts or traffic with Old Powers; but being an ignorant woman among
>   ignorant folk, she often used her crafts to foolish and dubious ends.
>   She knew nothing of the **Balance** and the **Pattern** which the true wizard
>   knows and serves, and which keep him from using his spells unless real
>   need demands. She had a spell for every circumstance, and was forever
>   wearing charms. Much of her lore was mere rubbish and humbug, nor did
>   she know the true spells from the false. She knew many curses, and was
>   better at causing sickness, perhaps, than at curing it. Like any
>   village witch she could brew up a love-potion, but there were other,
>   uglier brews she made to serve men's jealousy and hate."

Girls (at least in the first three books) are not allowed to study magic on the Island of Roke. Why is that? 
Their magic being 'weak' and 'wicked' is the cause or the consequence of not being allowed to study there?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehanu#Gender_issues

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Hm, interesting. Haven't read *Tehanu* yet, but it seems from your link that the setting in regard of the rules about magic abilities had changed quite a lot after the third book.

Comment: TL:DR There was no difference at all.

Comment: This was actually the subject of my Women's Literature final paper some years ago! Well, part of it. Can I copy and paste? ;)

Comment: @Adamant in this case -sure, pls do, i am very intrigued

Comment: It's pretty clearly the consequence, not the cause. Women are shown as living relatively cossetted experiences in Earthsea, and the breaking free from patriarchal roles is a subtle aspect of the stories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Probably none (with caveats)

It’s hard to tease out the nature of magic in Earthsea, because much of what we have comes from people’s opinions. Further, Le Guin’s conception of her world seems to have evolved over the many decades in which she wrote in it, making it difficult to pin down a specific opinion.

That said, Le Guin’s most recent statement on this matter, in *Tales from Earthsea*, seems clear:

> **Sorcery was practiced by men—its only real distinction from witchery.**
> Sorcerers trained one another, and had some knowledge of the True
> Speech.
>
> <sub>*Tales from Earthsea* (2001), “The School on Roke”</sub>

This would tend to suggest that there is no difference whatsoever between female power and male power in Earthsea.

Nonetheless, a more complete understanding of the question requires understanding how Le Guin’s views have evolved over time, and what influences have shaped them.

### Initial conception

In the early books of Earthsea, Le Guin seems to have been writing from a very traditional high fantasy conception. Better than most, of course—Le Guin was always a very good writer—but still heavily following the conventions of the genre, which, at that point, were fairly firmly established.<sup>1</sup>

Among these conventions were things such as the power of true names, secluded priestesses, wise shapeshifting wizards—and an intensely male focus. Evil sorceresses who tempt the pure hero, wicked witches who understand little of real magic—all of these were fairly prevalent ideas in fantasy when Le Guin was writing. As such, it seems likely that she reproduced these ideas in her books out of genre adherence.

*However*, for the purpose of viewing Le Guin’s Earthsea works as a consistent whole, it’s worth noting that the specific condescending views about women’s magic that are expressed are often implied to be in-universe:

> **There is a saying on Gont**, Weak as woman’s magic, and there is another
> saying, Wicked as woman’s magic.
>
> <sub>*A Wizard of Earthsea* (1968)</sub>

Though these opinions sometimes seep through to the narrator, I cannot help but wonder whether Le Guin was actually taking a rather anthropological approach to these views on magic, as she has often done: presenting, not judging, but also not agreeing. Barely a year later, after all, Le Guin published *The Left Hand of Darkness*, which rejected traditional gender roles and had a foolish protagonist limited thereby. Did Le Guin expect us to take the sayings of Gont seriously? Or did she want us to see them as the trite expressions of a patriarchal system? I cannot say for certain.

### Later conceptions

Over the years, I believe, Le Guin became more heavily influenced by Taoism. This seeped into her book in a plethora of manners. We can see,  for example, the influence of Taoism on how Le Guin’s conception of death changed from *A Wizard of Earthsea* to *The Other Wind*. Does [this statement](http://www.taoistsanctuary.org/22-questions-on-taoism/) of Taoist beliefs on death resemble anything?

> The older systems see the soul as separated into the Hun and Po, the
> spirit and vital souls which separate at death .The Hun may be
> developed sufficiently to retain integrity and move to a higher
> vibrational plane or simply be reintegrated with the source. **The Po,
> the vital soul becomes reintegrated with the earthbound source
> energies of the planet.**

Let us then consider this conversation from *Tehanu*:

> “I don’t know,” Tenar said. “It seems to me we make up most of the
> differences, and then complain about ‘em. I don’t see why the Art
> Magic, why power, should be different for a man witch and a woman
> witch. Unless the power itself is different. Or the art.”
>
> “A man gives out, dearie. A woman takes in.”
>
> Tenar sat silent but unsatisfied.
>
> “Ours is only a little power, seems like, next to theirs,” Moss said.
> “But it goes down deep. It’s all roots. It’s like an old blackberry
> thicket. And a wizard’s power’s like a fir tree, maybe, great and tall
> and grand, but it’ll blow right down in a storm. Nothing kills a
> blackberry bramble.” She gave her hen-chuckle, pleased with her
> comparison.
>
> <sub>*Tehanu* (1990)</sub>

This conception of magic presented in *Tehanu*, though nominally one character’s opinion, is highly reminiscint of Taoist notions of *yin* and *yang*, which to an extent can be though of  as feminine and masculine. As such, I believe it to be the conception of the “real” nature of male and female power in Earthsea that Le Guin had as she was writing *Tehanu.*

It’s difficult to say how this is reconciled with the statements from *Tales from Earthsea*. One possibility is that while witchcraft and sorcery were *magically* the same, men and women put them to different uses:

> Witches paid dearly for practicing the arts they thought of as their
> own. The care of pregnant beasts and women, birthing, teaching the
> songs and rites, the fertility and order of field and garden, the
> building and care of the house and its furniture, the mining of ores
> and metals—these great things had always been in the charge of women.
> A rich lore of spells and charms to ensure the good outcome of such
> undertakings was shared among the witches.
>
> <sub>*Tales from Earthsea* (2001), “The Finder”</sub>

Le Guin would, I think, attribute this to differences in the psychology of men and women, viewing female and male perspectives (*yin* and *yang*) as two separate but equally valid and powerful ways of accessing the same reality (with a great deal of overlap in what they are capable of, per *Tales from Earthsea*, but perhaps not in what they are used to accomplish):

> Two things, one origin, but different in name, whose identity is
> mystery. Mystery of all mysteries! The door to the hidden.
>
> <sub>*Lao Tzu: Tao Te Ching: A Book about the Way and the Power of the Way* (1997)</sub>

It is, however, also possible that this could be attributed to purely cultural factors, with no difference between male and female magic even at the psychological level, or conversely that there might be subtle differences in the powers available to women and men, a la *saidin* and *saidar* from Wheel of Time.

One thing that is clear, though, is that the view of women’s magic as weaker than men’s, or more malevolent, is nothing more than prejudice:

> It was then that village sorcery, and above all women’s witchery, came
> into the ill repute that has clung to it since.
>
> <sub>*Tales from Earthsea* (2001), “The Finder”</sub>

The decision to ban women from Roke was both unjustified, and ironic, given that women played a major role in its founding:

> Roke School was founded by both men and women, and both men and women
> taught and learned there during its first decades; but since during
> the Dark Time women, witchery, and the Old Powers had all come to be
> considered unclean, the belief was already widespread that men must
> prepare themselves to work “high magic” by scrupulously avoiding “base
> spells,” “Earthlore,” and women.
>
> <sub>*Tales from Earthsea* (2001), Celibacy and Wizardry”</sub>

So women’s magic being “weak” and “wicked” is neither cause nor consequence, being simply untrue. But the *idea* that women’s magic is base or inferior is *both* cause and consequence of their exclusion from Roke: Cause, because it is clearly shown to have existed before the founding of Roke. And consequence, because it is also shown that the policies of Roke reinforced these beliefs.

### The bottom line

**Women and men have equal power in Earthsea. But that power might tend toward different uses—whether because of actual differences in the magic available to men and women, or because of what (to Le Guin’s mind) are the real-life differences between female and male outlooks.**

**Beliefs about the *inferiority* of women’s magic are both untrue and of recent vintage.**

<sub><sup>1. Though we should not underestimate the extent to which Le Guin codified and even potentially established some of these ideas, too: the nature of true name magic in Earthsea has heavily influenced later writers.</sup></sub>

Comment: See, that's exactly why i am here.
To learn from people like you. Great answer.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if Terry Pratchett was influenced by the male sky magic of the wizards vs the earth magic of the witches.

Comment: @GerryColl Equal Rites is parody of Wizard of Earthsea, so... he was quite influenced...

Answer (score 0):

From the implications of LeGuin's language describing the geography of EarthSea (and [this map](http://www.ursulakleguin.com/EarthseaMaps/map_3736x2823.jpg))
the dark-skinned people of Roke shared rumors of magic-using white people from the north who used it to devious ends, which could possibly explain why the people of Roke and neighboring islands thought it a bad idea to teach girls magic, which could also explain why there are no girls in the academy Geb goes to to learn magic.

That paragraph in context may also be the opinion of people in the southern islands, and not the "law" per say.

Comment: This is terrible answer. Pure speculation based on what happened to Ged on Osskil. To answer this question well, the info from newer books is needed.